# Dynamic Scoring Table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, ranking

This is the simplified code for the scoreboard. What I am trying to build is a table that auto sorts itself by Total Points and assigns the rank of 1 for the lowest score and increments rank up from there until everyone has a rank. If 2 people have the same score the rank would be a T then the number.

```
<?php
$sql_score = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from event_scoreboard WHERE workoutid = '$work_out[$workout_counter]'");
    $rowcount1=mysqli_num_rows($sql_score);     
    $array = array();
    while($objscore = $sql_score->fetch_object()) { 
        $score = $objscore->score;

        $total_score += $score * 3; 
    }

    $values = array($total_score);
    $ordered_values = $values;
    echo rsort($ordered_values);

    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($ordered_values as $ordered_key => $ordered_value) {
            if ($value === $ordered_value) {
                $key = $ordered_key;
                break;
            }                          
        }
        echo $value . '- Rank: ' . ((int) $key + 1) . '<br/>';
    }
?>
```

The test code below works fine, but how can we achieve the same output by inserting those outputs from the while condition into a multi-dimentional array 
ex. $values = array($total_score);

Right now, i'm getting this output below. It only displays the array index['0'] which is why the Rank is 1 in all output.

```
13087 - Rank: 1
11029 - Rank: 1
110359 - Rank: 1
17035 - Rank: 1
19702 - Rank: 1
1702 - Rank: 1
196 - Rank: 1
19 - Rank: 1
110266 - Rank: 1
```

Working example to display the ranking based on score (currently DESC but it needs to be in ASC order - lowest score would be the rank # 1)

```
$values = array();
$values[0] = 13389;
$values[1] = 71298;
$values[2] = 234;
$values[3] = 9069;
$values[4] = 9936;
$values[5] = 2673;
$values[6] = 234;
$values[7] = 234;
$values[8] = 11634;
$values[9] = 1470;

$ordered_values = $values;
    echo rsort($ordered_values);

foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($ordered_values as $ordered_key => $ordered_value) {
        if ($value === $ordered_value) {
            $key = $ordered_key;
            break;
        }                          
    }
    echo $value . '- Rank: ' . ((int) $key + 1) . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for using PHP's [`rsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) is as follows:

```
bool rsort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
```

So, executing the line `echo rsort($ordered_values)` will evaluate to `true` on succuss (echoed as `1`) or `false` on failure (echoed `0`).

If you `print_r()` your `$ordered_values` array, you'll notice that it is in fact sorted in reverse order:

```
//the output I got
Array ( [0] => 71298 [1] => 13389 [2] => 11634 [3] => 9936 [4] => 9069 [5] => 2673 [6] => 1470 [7] => 234 [8] => 234 [9] => 234 )
```

*Meaning that the lowest ranked number comes in the end.*

**Note:** I assume that you actually intended the opposite of the outcome you get from your code. Not sure why you won't use the opposite of `rsort()` i.e. `sort()` to achieve your desired result.

Changing from `rsort()` to `sort()` would produce the following result:

```
13389- Rank: 9
71298- Rank: 10
234- Rank: 1
9069- Rank: 6
9936- Rank: 7
2673- Rank: 5
234- Rank: 1
234- Rank: 1
11634- Rank: 8
1470- Rank: 4
```

Comment: That does make sense but before I can fix that part does anyone have any feedback on the issue I am having with the multi dimensional array? It is returning rank 1 for everything.

Comment: The output that you see in my answer is the one with your code, except for changing `rsort` to `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing why you need the complexity of the multi-dimensional array.  Why not just use an [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) on the $value array?  That will sort the $value array by value from low to high and will keep the key associations.